# C# Can i implement interface with IEnumerable object and struct?

Tags: c#, struct, interface

So I want to write an interface, which should be able to be implemented with any data. This is interface i wrote till now. The reason I chose IEnumerable is because I need to give class Computer or struct Processor

```
 public interface IData<T> where T : IEnumerable<object>
{
    public T ReadData();
    public void WriteData(T list);
}
```

And I have two different datas, one is Computer, which is a class. And the other one is Processor (struct)

```
public struct Processor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AmazonLink { get; set; }
    public  string AmazonBin { get; set; }

    public Processor(string name, string link)
    {
        Name = name;
        try
        {
            //constructor parses elements which is needed to generate AmazonURL in URLGenerator project

            AmazonLink = link.Substring(0, link.IndexOf("&dc"));
            string binStart = link.Substring(link.IndexOf("bin%") + 4);
            AmazonBin = "%7C" + binStart.Substring(2);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new InnerCustomException("Erorr occured while trying to substring the link", e);
        }
    }
```

I tried to do that like this, but it seems like I am not allowed to do that because of boxing?

```
public class ProcessorServiceCSV : IData<IEnumerable<Processor>>
{   private string Path { get; set; }
    private FileMode Filemode { get; set; }
    public ProcessorServiceCSV(string path, FileMode fileMode)
    {
        Path = path;
        Filemode = fileMode;
    }
    //reads Processor list from CSV file
    public IEnumerable<Processor> ReadData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Path))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ProcessorMap>();
                var records = csv.GetRecords<Processor>().ToList();

                return records.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            throw new DataCustomException("File not found", this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new DataCustomException("Something's wrong happened:" + e.Message, this);
        }
    } public void WriteData(IEnumerable<Processor> processors)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = File.Open(Path, Filemode))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
            using (CsvWriter cw = new CsvWriter(sw))
            {
                foreach (Processor processor in processors)
                {
                    cw.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ProcessorMap>();
                    cw.WriteRecord<Processor>(processor);
                    cw.NextRecord();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            throw new DataCustomException("File not found", this);
        }
        catch (FileLoadException)
        {
            throw new DataCustomException("File could not be opened", this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new DataCustomException("Something's wrong happened:" + e.Message, this);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I know I could change Processor from struct to class, but is it possible to keep struct? Thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot treat a `IEnumerable<object>` as an `IEnumerable<Processor>`

Comment: `Computer` and `Processor` must share something in common in order to re-use use intended for both types. Please [edit] your question and show the definition of `Computer` as well as how it is used. No need all the code, just the minimum skeleton code that ties everything together. Also indicate where does the compiler indicate an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of other problems, including not giving us a complete, working bit of code.

However, it looks like you should be able to do what you want to do if you use an *Interface* for the `Processor` struct instead of the actual struct type.

Also, notice how I changed the type for `T` in your classes. You don't need `IEnumerable` in your `T` constraint. I did delete some of your code to get it to somewhat work (the exception in the struct constructor, e.g.), so you will need to do some more work here.

```cs
public interface IData<T>
{
     IEnumerable<T> ReadData();
     void WriteData(IEnumerable<T> list);
}

public interface IProcessor {
    string Name { get; set; }
    string AmazonLink { get; set; }
    string AmazonBin { get; set; }
}

public struct Processor : IProcessor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AmazonLink { get; set; }
    public  string AmazonBin { get; set; }

    public Processor(string name, string link)
    {
        Name = name;
            //constructor parses elements which is needed to generate AmazonURL in URLGenerator project

            AmazonLink = link.Substring(0, link.IndexOf("&dc"));
            string binStart = link.Substring(link.IndexOf("bin%") + 4);
            AmazonBin = "%7C" + binStart.Substring(2);
    }
}

public class ProcessorServiceCSV<T> : IData<T> where T: IProcessor
{   private string Path { get; set; }
    private FileMode Filemode { get; set; }
    public ProcessorServiceCSV(string path, FileMode fileMode)
    {
        Path = path;
        Filemode = fileMode;
    }
    //reads Processor list from CSV file
    public IEnumerable<T> ReadData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Path))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ProcessorMap>();
                var records = csv.GetRecords<Processor>().ToList();

                return records.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            throw new DataCustomException("File not found", this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new DataCustomException("Something's wrong happened:" + e.Message, this);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I know I could do generics like that, but the problem is that I want to use the same interface with class Computer and struct Processor. So this method will let me use only interface and not class or struct

Comment: If you want to operate on the different objects/structs without casting to a specific type, they should all have the same contract (interface). You can rename the interface however you like, but all your objects and structs should implement the interface to be able to used with this service. If you need different handling based on the type, you'd probably be better off creating separate processing services and using a factory pattern to get the correct processing service.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the basic skeleton code of what you are trying to do? Note that the generic collection is `IEnumerable<T>` and not `IEnumetable<object>` and hence I updated your `IData<T>` definition

```
public class Computer
{
}

public struct Processor
{
}

public interface IData<T> 
{
    IEnumerable<T> ReadData();
    void WriteData(IEnumerable<T> list);
}


public class ComputerData : IData<Computer>
{
    public IEnumerable<Computer> ReadData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteData(IEnumerable<Computer> list)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class ProcessorData : IData<Processor>
{
    public IEnumerable<Processor> ReadData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteData(IEnumerable<Processor> list)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Please indicate if this code meets your requirements, and if not why.